# How to normalize data on import efficiently?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a flat file containing denormalized data.  For good reasons, I can't change this.  I need to get it into normalized, related tables for use in [LightSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851953.aspx).  The data does not contain identity column values for any of the original tables.  I have four columns:

```
Division    Branch    Position    Location
```

The schema for the normalised data is: Divisions contain Branches.  Branches contain Positions.  Positions and Locations have a many-to-many relationship via a PositionLocationMappings table.

I do a BULK INSERT to get the denormalized data into a table.  Then, I process it row by row, calling a stored procedure for each row.  There are around 16,000 rows in the source file and it takes 27 seconds, which seems a bit slow.  Is there a way to do it faster?

This is in my PostDeployment.sql script:

```
DECLARE @division nvarchar(240)
DECLARE @branch nvarchar(240)
DECLARE @position nvarchar(240)
DECLARE @location nvarchar(60)

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT Division,Branch,Position,Location
        FROM [staging].BranchPositions

OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @division, @branch, @position, @location

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_InsertBranchPositions] @division,@branch,@position,@location

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @division, @branch, @position, @location
END

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

And here's the stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertBranchPositions] 
    @division nvarchar(240),
    @branch   nvarchar(240),
    @position nvarchar(240),
    @location nvarchar(60)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @divisionTable TABLE (InsertedDivisionId int)
    DECLARE @branchTable   TABLE (InsertedBranchId   int)
    DECLARE @positionTable TABLE (InsertedPositionId int)
    DECLARE @locationTable TABLE (InsertedLocationid int)

    DECLARE @divisionId int
    DECLARE @branchId   int
    DECLARE @positionId int
    DECLARE @locationId int

    SELECT @divisionId = [Id] FROM [dbo].[Divisions]
     WHERE DivisionName = @division

    IF @divisionId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Divisions] (DivisionName, IsDivisionActive)
             VALUES (@division, 1)
        SELECT @divisionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    SELECT @branchId = [Id] FROM [dbo].[Branches]
     WHERE BranchName = @branch

    IF @branchId IS NULL
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[Branches] (BranchName, IsBranchActive, DivisionId)
             VALUES (@branch, 1, @divisionId)
        SELECT @branchId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    SELECT @positionId = [Id] FROM [dbo].[Positions]
     WHERE PositionName = @position

    IF @positionId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Positions] (PositionName, IsPositionActive, BranchId)
             VALUES (@position, 1, @branchId)
        SELECT @positionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    SELECT @locationId = [Id] FROM [dbo].[Locations]
     WHERE LocationName = @location

    IF @locationId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Locations] (LocationName, IsLocationActive)
             VALUES (@location, 1)
        SELECT @locationId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PositionLocationMappings] (PositionId, LocationId)
         VALUES (@positionId, @locationId)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling a procedure for each row, you could import the data with set-based operations.

For example, you can change the work done by this snippet:

```
IF @divisionId IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Divisions] (DivisionName, IsDivisionActive)
         VALUES (@division, 1)
    SELECT @divisionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

To:

```
insert  Divisions 
        (DivisionName, IsDivisionActive)
select  distinct DivisionName
,       1
from    BranchPositions
```

Then for `Branches`, you would use a `join` to look up the `DivisionId`:

```
insert  Branches
        (BranchName, IsBranchActive, DivisionId)
select  distinct BranchName
,       1
,       d.Id
from    BranchPositions bp
join    Divisions d
on      bp.DivisionName = d.DivisionName
```

And so on.  That should be much faster, I've used it to import billions of rows in under a minute.

Comment: It is the same as always -- removing IF statements and cursors in SQL speeds up querys

Comment: Thanks for that.  It now runs in less than a second.